# Android OS hiding full USB tree

Tags: android

Is there a way of discovering the full USB tree from within an Android Application? The current USB Host `API` only provides a list of all the devices and their endpoints. I need to be able to associate the device with a particular port on the USB hub. In Windows I can see what port number each devices is on.

It appears that the Android OS masks the hub from view.

I thought about trying to access Linux through JNI, however, the app at the commentary at:
 https://github.com/alt236/USB-Device-Info---Android, suggests that it doesn't appear in Linux too.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just walk the hardware tree. For instance, on my Nook it's /sys/devices/platform/musb_hdrc/usb1. [Here's a screenshot of my app.](http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/685ad2b27c1a7f80ebe71baba305bb25/50007f97/1/1/3/8/1/5/6/usbmode2.jpg)

Comment: the link to the screenshot is broken, saying: *410 - Gone*